# Elementary OS Upgrade error

Tags: ubuntu, updates, elementaryos

I have Elementary OS Freya (Ubuntu 14.04) and I want to upgrade to wily (Ubuntu 15.10). It says that an upgrade is available:

[image: screenshot]

Then I get this window:

[image: screenshot]

and I click Upgrade. And then this error (see the comment below) shows up. I have tried running `apt-get update` and it didn't work.

Comment: http://imgur.com/cAaDfXX

Comment: Did you tried with `sudo apt-get update` and after `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` or with `sudo do-release-upgrade`? They work for Ubuntu. `do-release-upgrade` is reported to have the ability to handle system configuration changes sometimes needed between releases.

Comment: it says invalid operation dist

Comment: It [seems](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/198436/66388) that still in the last April _"Elementary does not provides an upgrade path from update manager."_. You can __Backup All__, do a starting disk, boot from that and select _"upgrade"_. Or you can __Backup All__ and do a fresh install.
ps> did I just said __Backup All__? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Elementary_OS_WIki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_OS#0.4_Loki) the Future release is the elementary OS 0.4 Loki , it’s called Ubuntu 15.04 because it's under developpement. The reason it says that an upgrade is available because you have enabled 'distribution upgrade'